# Assigning multiple objects to a dict() in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

My question may or may not be pretty straightforward. Is it possible to assign multiple variables/objects to a dict() function in Python?
For example, I have a code snippet -

```
node_id = None
c_node = None
node_range = range(4)
nodes_memory = None

def init():
    global nodes_memory
    nodes_memory = dict()
    for node_id in node_range:
        nodes_memory[node_id] = dict()
    for c_node in node_range:
        nodes_memory[c_node] = dict()
```

Will `nodes_memory` only store values of `node_id` from `node_range` (or `c_node` from `node_range` or neither will do so)?
If either of the above cases is true, how do I store both values in `nodes_memory` so that I can access them using `[""]` at any point in time?
Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: you're not using your data... dict isn't used here. you're printing values of `range`

Comment: Okay so assuming I do not use the second function, how do I store both `node_id` and `c_node` values into the `dict()` function?

Comment: Don't use global variables if at all possible. Return the dict instead.
For each key in dict you can only have one value, however that value can be a container that has several elements. E.g. tuple, list, another nested dict.

You can't access any of the things you added to dict by [""] because that key does not exist. You might want to use 

for key, value in dict.items():

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is it you're trying to store in `nodes_memory`? Each time you assign a key to value in this way, the last value is overwritten. It looks like you're trying to assign every key to a new `dict`

Comment: @JoonatanSamuel Thanks for the answer. Actually by `[""]` I meant to say `[node_id]` or `[c_node]` in `nodes_memory[""]`. The `""` was just a sort of reference to them in the question. So then we can't add both `node_id` and `c_node` into `nodes_memory` (`dict()`)? :(

Comment: I'm actually trying to store keys of different variables into `dict()` to access them later in my code @mangoHero1

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a mapping where each key is mapped to a single value. Keys are unique and cannot be more than one of the same key. To create a "multidict", I would use a `defaultdict` from the `collections` module.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def init():
    nodes_memory = defaultdict(list)
    node_range = range(4)
    for node_id in node_range:
        nodes_memory[node_id].append(node_id)
    for c_node in node_range:
        nodes_memory[c_node].append(c_node)
    return nodes_memory
```

You can replace the value in `append` with whatever other value you like. To access values, use index notation like you would with a regular `dict`.